# Local kriging reports error in `krigeST` with full data (`STFDF`)

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

I have been playing around with the `krigeST` function in the `gstat` package, and I tried to do local kriging with a full set of SpatialPolygons based data (STFDF).

When I tried the following

```
spatio_time_krige_sumProd = krigeST(conso~1, 
                                    some_STFDF_with_SpatialPolygons_in_sp, 
                                    newdata = some_STF_with_SpatialPolygons_in_sp,                      
                                    fitted_prodSum_variogram, 
                                    nmax = 50, 
                                    stAni = 4)
Error in from@sp[from@index[, 1], ] : 
   SpatialPolygons selection: can't find plot order if polygons are replicated
```

What seems to be the problem is that in krigeST.local, the `some_STFDF_with_SpatialPolygons_in_sp` is coerced into a `SFIDF`. In that, there is a subsetting step which is not allowed by the `SpatialPolygons` class, since there are repeated terms in `from@index[, 1]`.

I'd like to try non-separable spatio-temporal variogram, so not using local kriging isn't really an option. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Kriging is usually thought as interpolating from observed points to non-observed points. Why do you pass polygons to the function?

Comment: My data is actually area-based, so to be really rigorous, I should probably consider block spatio-temporal kriging. However that seems to be much more expensive computationally. Maybe I should just remplace the polygons with their geometric centers.

Comment: It's called area-to-point (or area-to-area) kriging. I cannot recommend replacing the polygons with their center points.